# How to apply a displacement map to a plane in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I want to display an image with an associated displacement map in A-Frame. My goal is to give the image a 3D depth effect in the style of Facebook 3D Photos. The image and the depth map are 1024x1024 PNGs.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <title>Displacement</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="texture" src="texture.png">
        <img id="displacement" src="displacement.png">
      </a-assets>
      <a-plane
        src="#texture"
        width="250"
        height="250"
        position="0 0 -200"
        displacement-map="#displacement"
        displacement-bias="0"
        displacement-scale="60"
      ></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

This displays a plane textured with the image, but it's flat with no displacement effect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The displacement map only moves the existing vertices of the plane, i.e. the corners. In order to get a mapped displacement effect, you need to subdivide the plane into smaller triangles with the `segments-height` and `segments-width` attributes.